# Restoring older firmware through XCode?

Tags: xcode, downgrade, ios

I'm trying to restore iPhone OS 3.1.3 to a 3GS that has been upgraded to iOS 4. iTunes refuses to complete the install. What needs to be done? I am currently using the GM XCode. Should I be using the latest public stable version instead?

Update:

XCode reports that "The baseband cannot be rolled back".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.tipb.com/2010/05/12/howto-downgrade-iphone-40-313/) has some answers.

BlackRa1n gets the iPhone out of the reboot loop after a failed baseband rollback.